# "Message: invalid session id" during web-scraping

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a website that had HTML code that looks like this:

[HTML Screen shtot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOPLP.jpg)

My web-scraping code looks like this for now:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

url = "https://iclr.cc/virtual_2020/papers.html?filter=keywords"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get(url)
stages = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('stage-scheduled')
driver.close()

c = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")

title = soup.find_all('div', {'class':"myCard col-xs-6 col-md-4"})
print (len(title))
```

The problem is I keep getting "InvalidSessionIdException: Message: invalid session id".

May I know how to solve this problem? Thank you in advance!